# Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to construct a single http request consisting of several sub-requests using mime/multipart requests. Here is my client code:

```
def build_request( url, type, headers, data = {}):

    request = MIMEBase("application", "http")

    #Build appropriate request
    if type == "get":
        request.data = Request('GET', url, headers=headers)

    elif type == "post":
        request.data = Request('POST', url, data = json.dumps(data), headers = {'Content-Type':'application/http'})

    elif type == "delete":
        request.data = Request('DELETE', url, headers = {'Content-Type':'application/http'})

    elif type == "put":
        request.data = Request('PUT', url, data = json.dumps(data), headers = {'Content-Type':'application/http'})

    elif type == "patch":
        request.data = Request('PATCH', url, data = json.dumps(data), headers = {'Content-Type':'application/http'})

    return request

if __name__ == '__main__':

    url = "http://localhost:65200/api";

    #Get customers
    get_customers = build_request( url + "/Customers", "get", headers)

    #Add a customer
    add_customer = build_request( url + "/Customers", "post", data=added_customer, headers=headers)

    #update a customer
    update_customer = build_request( url + "/Customers/{0}".format(updated_customer["Id"]), "put", data=updated_customer, headers=headers)

    #Remove a customer
    remove_customer = build_request( url + "/Customers/{0}".format(removed_customer["Id"]), "delete", headers=headers)

    s = Session()

    uuid = uuid.uuid4()

    message = MIMEMultipart("mixed", "batch_{0}".format(uuid), [get_customers,add_customer,update_customer,remove_customer])

    headers = {'Content-Type':'multipart/mixed; boundary=\"{0}\"'.format(uuid)}


    #Error here    
    reply = requests.post(url + "/batch", data = message.as_string(), headers=headers)
```

Error:

> '{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unexpected
>   end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not
>   complete.","ExceptionType":"System.IO.IOException","StackTrace":"   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.Parsers.MimeMultipartBodyPartParser.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.d__8.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.d__0`1.MoveNext()\\r\\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\\r\\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\\r\\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Batch.DefaultHttpBatchHandler.d__13.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\\r\\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Batch.DefaultHttpBatchHandler.<ProcessBatchAsync>d__1.MoveNext()\\r\\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\\r\\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\\r\\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Batch.HttpBatchHandler.d__0.MoveNext()"}'

Does anybody have an idea of how to fix this?

Captured fiddler session:

```
POST http://localhost:65200/api/batch HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:65200
Content-Length: 535
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="7ef5c2df-3aa4-4e8c-bb47-8c9105bc3457"
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.1.0 CPython/2.7.6 Windows/7

Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="batch_7ef5c2df-3aa4-4e8c-bb47-8c9105bc3457"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--batch_7ef5c2df-3aa4-4e8c-bb47-8c9105bc3457
Content-Type: application/http
MIME-Version: 1.0


--batch_7ef5c2df-3aa4-4e8c-bb47-8c9105bc3457
Content-Type: application/http
MIME-Version: 1.0


--batch_7ef5c2df-3aa4-4e8c-bb47-8c9105bc3457
Content-Type: application/http
MIME-Version: 1.0


--batch_7ef5c2df-3aa4-4e8c-bb47-8c9105bc3457
Content-Type: application/http
MIME-Version: 1.0


--batch_7ef5c2df-3aa4-4e8c-bb47-8c9105bc3457--
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcbXJ5YW4uQVNBVklFXERvY3VtZW50c1xWaXN1YWwgU3R1ZGlvIDIwMTNcUHJvamVjdHNcQmF0Y2hTYW1wbGVcQmF0Y2hTYW1wbGVcYXBpXGJhdGNo?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 28 Apr 2014 15:31:48 GMT
Content-Length: 2075

{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete.","ExceptionType":"System.IO.IOException","StackTrace":"   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.Parsers.MimeMultipartBodyPartParser.<ParseBuffer>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.<MultipartReadAsync>d__8.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.<ReadAsMultipartAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Batch.DefaultHttpBatchHandler.<ParseBatchRequestsAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Batch.DefaultHttpBatchHandler.<ProcessBatchAsync>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Batch.HttpBatchHandler.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"}
```

Comment: are you using Web API 2 or 2.1+. Please try with 2.1 and let me know if it's still there.

Comment: Just checked in NuGet, I'm using 2.1, I also updated all the installed packages - getting the same symptoms

Comment: Can you share a fiddler session?

Comment: I've updated my post with a captured session (I haven't used fiddler before so let me know if you need anymore info)